# Bitbucket pipeline env variables

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm deploying my react app to the s3 bucket and I have a lot of env variables, so the question is how can I handle the env variables in bitbucket pipelines?

error in pipeline

```
+ npm run build
> app@0.1.0 build /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
> env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts build  && cp build/index.html build/200.html
Error: Failed to find .env file at path: .env.prod
    at getEnvFile (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/env-cmd/dist/get-env-vars.js:40:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.1.0 build: `env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts build  && cp build/index.html build/200.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-03-01T10_17_14_844Z-debug.log
```

bitbucket-pipeline.yml

```
image: node:10

# Workflow Configuration

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
            # CI=true in default variables for Bitbucket Pipelines https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-in-pipelines/
      
  branches:
    master:
      - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            caches:
              - node
            script:
              - npm install
              # CI=true in default variables for Bitbucket Pipelines https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-in-pipelines/
              - npm run build
            artifacts:
              - build/**
        - step:
            name: Security Scan
            script:
              # Run a security scan for sensitive data.
              # See more security tools at https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?&category=security
              - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.5.1
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          deployment: Production
          trigger: manual
          clone:
            enabled: false
          script:
            # sync your files to S3
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:1.1.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
                LOCAL_PATH: 'build'
            # triggering a distribution invalidation to refresh the CDN caches
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-cloudfront-invalidate:0.6.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                DISTRIBUTION_ID: '123xyz'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've my env variables in my `.env` file, so how can I add env variables in bucket pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found so far is using bitbucket variables, and passing them into the pipeline.
Relevent snippet from the support article:

> Workspace variables
>
> Variables specified for a workspace can be accessed from all repositories that belong to the workspace. You must be an
> administrator to manage workspace variables.
>
> From your avatar in the bottom left, select a workspace.
>
> Select Settings on the left navigation sidebar to open your Workspace settings.
> In the menu on the left, go to  Pipelines > Workspace variables.
>
> Workspaces variables can be overridden by repository variables.
>
> Workspace variables can be accessed by all users with the write permission for any repository (private or public) that belongs to the team or account.
>
> You must be an administrator of a workspace or a repository to manage  variables respectively.

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/

Answer (score -1):

Simply add a line in the script where you need the variables and load the file:

```
- export $(cat .env | xargs)
```

Comment: for that do I need to put my `.env` file in my repo?

Comment: I don't want to put that file in my repo, because it has some secrects.

Comment: So you want to use a file on your computer? For processes that run unattended on a remote server? I don't see how that should work. If you want to use secrets and other variables, you should use the mechanism for that: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/

Comment: Storing your environment variables in the repo is bad practice.